# Python - Conways Game of life

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

It seems my process isn't applying to the next iteration. I have deep copies in main, and I think the problem lies within them and when they are called.

Spacing is a little off, my apologies.

Problem is in my results, it prints the first iteration fine with the alive cells. Then the next iterations are blank and shows no change in cells.

```
LIVING_CELL = 'A'
DEAD_CELL = '.'

#Get the alive cells from the user
def getBoard(rows, cols, boardList):
   myList = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]

   while True:

        aliveRows = input("Please enter a row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): ")
        if aliveRows == 'q':
            break
        aliveCols = input("Please enter a column for that cell: ")
        print()
        myList[int(aliveRows)][int(aliveCols)] = 1
   return myList

#next board cells
def getNxtIter(cols, rows, cur, nxt):
    for i in range(1,rows-1):
        for j in range(1,cols-1):
            nxt[i][j] = getNeighbors(i, j, cur)

#Processing the neighbor cells
def getNeighbors(x, y, boardList):
    nCount = 0
    for j in range(y-1,y+2):
        for i in range(x-1,x+2):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                if boardList[i][j] != -1:
                    nCount += boardList[i][j]
    if boardList[x][y] == 1 and nCount < 2:
        return 0
    if boardList[x][y] == 1 and nCount > 3:
       return 1
    else:
        return boardList[x][y]

#Printing and forming the actual board
def printBoard(cols, rows, boardList):
    for i in range(rows+2):
        for j in range(cols+2):
            if boardList[i][j] == -1:
                print(DEAD_CELL, end=" ")
            elif boardList[i][j] == 1:
                print(LIVING_CELL, end=" ")
            else:
               print(DEAD_CELL, end=" ")
        print()

def main():
#Getting and validating the number of rows and columns
    x = 1
    while x ==1:

        rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
        if rows < 0:
            x = 1
        elif rows> 50:
            x = 1
        else:
            x =0

    n = 1
    while n == 1:
        cols = int(input("Please enter the number of columns: "))
        if cols < 0:
            n = 1
        elif cols > 50:
            n = 1
        else:
            n = 0

    boardList = []
    newBoardList = []
    boardList = getBoard(rows, cols, boardList)
    newBoardList = [x[:] for x in boardList]

    print()

#Getting iterations to run, and validating if <= 0
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        iterations = int(input("How many iterations should I run? "))+1
        if iterations <= 0:
            a = 1
        else:
            a = 0
    for count in range(iterations):
        print()
        print("Iteration:", count)
        print()
        printBoard(cols, rows, boardList)
        getNxtIter(cols, rows, boardList, newBoardList)
        boardList = [x[:] for x in newBoardList]
        newBoardList = [x[:] for x in boardList]
main()
```

Comment: please tell us where in your code you are running into problems

Comment: I second that.  If you edit the question to specify the specific error you are facing, we can try to help

Comment: Ah, sorry! I just edited at the top and also in the code where I believe my problem lies.

Comment: The code isn't indented properly.

Comment: Yeah , when I was pasting in the code the indention got a little messy.I thought I fixed all of it thought

Comment: OKAY, now the indentation is exactly how it should be! Sorry, first post.

Comment: Okay was it just the x = 1 ? If not i have no idea what you are talking about , it runs without any indentation errors on my end.

Comment: I know ! LOL im asking if that was the only indentation issue !

Comment: im super confused at whats going on. Did you @PaulRooney  fix them?

Comment: I did fix them, but you edited back over my edit, to break it again.

Comment: Oh -___-  sorry. And thanks!

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. And what the heck is Conways game ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be having problems applying the multiple changes from the other answer, here's a simplified and cleaned up version that I have tested and am certain works in Python 3:

```
LIVING_CELL = 'A'
DEAD_CELL = '.'

#Get the alive cells from the user
def getBoard(rows, cols):
    myList = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]
    while True:
        raw = input('Please enter "row <space> column", of a cell to turn on (RETURN to exit): ')
        if raw == '':
            break
        splitted = raw.split()
        if len(splitted) != 2:
            print("Invalid input")
        else:
            row, col = int(splitted[0]), int(splitted[1])
            if row >= rows or col >= cols:
                print("Invalid row/column value")
            else:
                myList[row][col] = 1
                printBoard(rows, cols, myList)
    return myList

#next board cells
def getNxtIter(rows, cols, cur, nxt):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            nxt[i][j] = getNeighbors(rows, cols, i, j, cur)

#Processing the neighbor cells
def getNeighbors(rows, cols, x, y, boardList):
    nCount = 0
    for j in range(y-1,y+2):
        for i in range(x-1,x+2):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                itest, jtest = i, j
                if itest == rows:
                    itest = 0
                if jtest == cols:
                    jtest = 0
                nCount += boardList[itest][jtest]
    if nCount == 3 or (boardList[x][y] == 1 and nCount == 2):
        return 1
    return 0

#Printing and forming the actual board
def printBoard(rows, cols, boardList):
    for i in range(rows):
        line = []
        for j in range(cols):
            if boardList[i][j] == 1:
                line.append(LIVING_CELL)
            else:
                line.append(DEAD_CELL)
        print("".join(line))

def main():
    #Getting and validating the number of rows and columns
    while True:
        rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
        if rows > 0 and rows <= 50:
            break

    while True:
        cols = int(input("Please enter the number of columns: "))
        if rows > 0 and rows <= 50:
            break

    boardList = getBoard(rows, cols)
    newBoardList = [x[:] for x in boardList]

    print()

    #Getting iterations to run, and validating if <= 0
    while True:
        iterations = int(input("How many iterations should I run? "))+1
        if iterations > 0:
            break

    for count in range(iterations):
        print()
        print("Iteration:", count)
        print()
        printBoard(rows, cols, boardList)
        getNxtIter(rows, cols, boardList, newBoardList)
        boardList, newBoardList = newBoardList, boardList

main()
```

I improved the performance of the printing code too, it got very slow with big boards.

I tested it by [firing a Glider at a Blinker on a 20x20 board](http://pastebin.com/w1wiYpRA), seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is crashing for me because you are indexing outside the end of the lists in `printBoard()`. This can be fixed by changing the ranges:

```
def printBoard(cols, rows, boardList):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
        ...
```

It's possible that other errors were fixed by cleaning up the indentation, it seems to at least apply the changes each iteration now.

You should probably be consistent about the order that the `rows, cols` parameters are passed around, to save you headaches later on.

Your Conway's algorithm in `getNeighbours()` doesn't look correct to me. Live cells should die unless they have 2 or 3 neighbours, and dead cells with 3 neighbours should come alive. The following is simpler and works correctly:

```
if nCount == 3 or (boardList[x][y] == 1 and nCount == 2):
    return 1
return 0
```

Another problem is that you don't process the cells along the edge of the board because of the ranges in `getNxtIter()`. Here are the changes needed to make the board 'wrap around':

```
#next board cells
def getNxtIter(cols, rows, cur, nxt):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            nxt[i][j] = getNeighbors(i, j, cur)

#Processing the neighbor cells
def getNeighbors(x, y, boardList):
    rows, cols = len(boardList), len(boardList[0])
    nCount = 0
    for j in range(y-1,y+2):
        for i in range(x-1,x+2):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                itest, jtest = i, j
                if itest == rows:
                    itest = 0
                if jtest == cols:
                    jtest = 0
                nCount += boardList[itest][jtest]
    if nCount == 3 or (boardList[x][y] == 1 and nCount == 2):
        return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: hmm thanks, when I try and add +1 or +2 to rows and cols it still gives me that error , why?

Comment: Create a list with `x=[1,2,3]` Then try `print(x[3])`. You'll get an `IndexError` exception because only `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` exist. Sequences are zero-indexed in Python, and most good languages :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, thats exactly what Im stuck on now . And im not sure how I would go about this. Working on just your snippet above, how would I implement comparing the outside rows and columns?

Comment: it still doesnt seem to be applying anything after the first iteration even after I applied your updates to my code?

Comment: Okay just recopied everything and now it seems to run the first one. Run the second one, then it repeats the second until the end. Im on python 3 if that effects anything.

Comment: There wasnt a need to change anything else in the printBoard function besides what you updated above correct?